# detecting scroll event on a page-scoped div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When a css file contains an instruction like this:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

A JS code like the following does not detect the scrolling event.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
   alert('this alert does not fire');
});
```

I guess with that css, there is no possibility of a scroll event and hence the reason why the scrolling event does not fire.

So I wrapped the entire page body content into a div, like this:

```
<body>

  <div canvas="container">
      the entire page content here
  </div>

</body>
```

In this case, what would be the correct version of the JS code below so we can catch these alerts in a timely fashion?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){

   if( $(window).scrollTop()>50 ){
       alert('1');
   } 
   else {
       alert('2');
   }
});
```

Comment: Is there anything in the body thats taller than the window width? Try setting the body and html height to 200% and see if it works.

Comment: canvas="container" is a confusing attribute. with class="container" and CSS: .container {min-height: 2000px;} you should get the scroll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a page is styled like:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
```

}

you cannot listen for the window scroll event because there is nothing to scroll.
Instead, you may use [mouse wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel):

```js
$(window).on('wheel', function(){
  console.log('this alert fires');
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

You may  handle the following events:

- wheel (when you use the mouse wheel)
- mousedown (when you click on the scroll bar of the doc to scroll)
- keydown (ctrl+home, ctrl+hend, down-up arrow, pgdown and pgup: keyboard scrolling)

The new snippet:

```js
$(document).on('wheel mousedown keydown', function(e){
  if (e.type == 'wheel' || (e.target.id == 'full-content-div' && e.type == 'mousedown' && e.clientX >= $('div[canvas="container"]').width()) ||
      (e.type == 'keydown' && ((e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode  == 36 || e.which == 35)) ||
                               (!e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode  == 33 || e.which == 34 || e.which == 38|| e.which == 40))))
     ) {
    console.log(e.type + ' event');
  }
});
```

```css
div[canvas="container"]{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div canvas="container" id="full-content-div">
    the entire page content here
</div>
```

Comment: That's interesting. But it is not the same as scroll. So if the user drag the scroll bar down or keyboard down arrow is involved, that event won't fire. Isn't there a way to detect the scrolling event on that div ( the one that wraps the entire page content )? The browser still mounts the vertical scroll bar to its usual spot. When  I right click and inspect the scroll bar, inspector points to the `<div canvas="container" id="full-content-div">`. In other sites, the scroller would point to <html>. Does this give us a clue in creating an alternative solution around the canvas-container div?

Comment: @AverageJoe I updated my answer adding a new snippet. I hope this could answer your question.

Comment: Dear gaetanoM, thanks a lot for taking the time to address all of the ways that a scroll event can be accounted for. I plugged in your code and sure enough, it does catch the scrolling - including the touchpad gesture! But... I still have to figure out a way to determine the scroll position. My whole goal in this endeavor was to *fix the navbar* when  `$(window).scrollTop()>50)` (which is the point to run `$('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed');` ). Do you have any suggestions that would pull that scroll position off? -- Also, pls correct the typo in your CSS snippet.

Comment: I already got that issue taken care of.  this interesting code gives me the sense of scrolling position. `var the_content = document.getElementById('full-content-div');
  var scrollPosition = JSON.stringify( getTopPosition( the_content ) );` and the function that makes it happen is as follows: `function getTopPosition(el){
   for (var pos=[0,0];el;el=el.offsetParent){
  pos[1] +=  el.offsetTop-el.scrollTop;
   }
   return -1 * pos[1]; 
 }`